# Sql Join Query Error. Some one please assist me

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my model function in laravel blade. In this i have two table `"admins"` and `"candidates"` using join query i join the two table. But While running my code I probably get this below mentioned
error.

```
if ( Input::has('recordcreator') and $request->input('recordcreator') != NULL){
            $querys->join('admins','admins.adminid','=','candidates.createdby');
            $querys->where('admins.firstname', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->input('recordcreator') .'%')->orWhere('admins.lastname', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->input('recordcreator') .'%')->where('admins.status','1'); 
        }
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column
>   'firstname' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from
>   rsi_candidates inner join rsi_admins on rsi_admins.adminid =
>   rsi_candidates.createdby where rsi_admins.lastname LIKE %ic%
>   and rsi_admins.status = 1 or rsi_admins.firstname LIKE %ic%
>   group by rsi_candidates.candidateid order by firstname asc limit
>   20 offset 0)

Comment: you will have to specify the name of the table from where you want the first name because first name field is present in both the table

Comment: But I already mentioned it bro. "'admins.firstname"

Comment: for order by you have not

Comment: Yeah Correct Bro. Now Its Functioning Like a Charm. Thanks a Lot _/\_

Comment: welcome brother:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
As i see your laravel error you may add the table name in front of your firstname column in orderby clause
```

Or you may also try this solution

```
open your database.php file located in config directory
Config->database.php  in your mysql database array add this.
```

'strict' => false,

Comment: Thanks a Lot Bro Surely I follow this too.